# create 2D array based on 3D array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Whats the most efficient way to create a 2D array based on a 3D array? I have the following input 3D array, which encodes the rgb information of a picture:

[[[255,255,255], [255,255,255], [255,255,255], ... ]]

i want to create a new 2D array which is a mask essentially, checking if the rgb values yield above a certain threshold:

[[true, false, true, false, ...]]

When i operate on each of the rgb values, I am doing a series of multiplications, additions and sqrts, and the final value of this operation determines the values of the 2D array output, either true or false.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I am trying to convert this C++ code to python:

```
cv::Mat diffImage;
cv::absdiff(backgroundImage, currentImage, diffImage);

cv::Mat foregroundMask = cv::Mat::zeros(diffImage.rows, diffImage.cols, CV_8UC1);

float threshold = 30.0f;
float dist;

for(int j=0; j<diffImage.rows; ++j)
    for(int i=0; i<diffImage.cols; ++i)
    {
        cv::Vec3b pix = diffImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);

        dist = (pix[0]*pix[0] + pix[1]*pix[1] + pix[2]*pix[2]);
        dist = sqrt(dist);

        if(dist>threshold)
        {
            foregroundMask.at<unsigned char>(j,i) = 255;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal reproducible example. Also a sample input/output would help. There are 3 values in each rib, how do you assign a single boolean value for them?

Comment: @Ehsan updated, please check edited post

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is

```
np.sqrt(np.sum(image ** 2, axis=2)) > threshold
```

Even better would be to write:

```
np.sum(image**2, axis=2) > threshold ** 2
```

since squaring the threshold is faster than taking the square root of every element in the array.

I think you can also use `axis=-1`, so that it always sums along the final axis, regardless of the dimensions of the array.

@MichaelChang reminds me that `sum` is both a function and a method.  This could be rewritten even more simply as:

```
(images**2).sum(axis=2) > threshold ** 2
```

Comment: got it, thank you good sir. A quick follow up question, what if I want the 2D output to be either 255, when previously it was true, or 0, when previously it was false?

Comment: @MichaelChang `((image**2).sum(2) > threshold**2)*255`. Please consider accepting the answer if it resolves your issue.

Comment: @MichaelChang.  Added the use of .sum(2) to my answer.